# video.js, playing video, but no sound on IE10

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm using video.js to embed my videos. Now we have the following problem by some Windows-User with IE 10. The video is playing, but without sound (yes, the speakers are on!). The MP4 File is ok, because if you open it directly every thing goes fine. Even on the official video.js website we have the same problem. Does anybody know about that? Is there some security issues about HTML5 Video and IE10? I tried google but couldn't find anything.

thanks for any help
best regards
thomas

Comment: Doesn't Windows have the ability to set the volume for each individual application? Is it possible that IE is simply muted? Try double-clicking the volume icon in the task bar to check.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try a different browser? Browers tend to differ in their use and acceptability of JS, HTML, Flash and display of these objects. Try chrome/Opera as it will accept all html5 objects and if you have problems with this you'll need to review your code.

Please provide code as right now I cannot tell you more with out seeing some code.

Here is a link of some one that had the same problem.
http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/1636-video-player-not-working-in-ie

And another link:
[HTML5 Video Not Working in IE9+10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792713/html5-video-not-working-in-ie910?rq=1)

The OP from this forum had to add these lines

```
AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType audio/webm .weba
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/x-m4v .m4v
```

Let Me know if you need anything more but I need to at least see some code please.

Thank you

EDIT:

Added code that worked for me, Try this out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
 <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
 <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
    </body>
</html>
```